# Spring Filter - "No thread-bound request found" if an invalid route was called

Tags: java, spring, filter, header, response

I want to add a `Correlation-Id` header to all responses by using a Spring filter. 
It worked great so far, but if I call a route which does not match to a resource I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exception.

My filter looks like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class AttachCorrelationIdHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AttachCorrelationIdHeaderFilter.class);

    private String correlationIdHeaderName = "";

    public AttachCorrelationIdHeaderFilter(String correlationIdHeaderName) {
        this.correlationIdHeaderName = correlationIdHeaderName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String correlationId = httpServletRequest.getHeader(this.correlationIdHeaderName);

        if (correlationId == null || correlationId.isEmpty()) {
            correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            LOGGER.debug("Generated new Correlation-Id {}", correlationId);
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Use existing Correlation-Id {}", correlationId);
        }

        httpServletResponse.addHeader(this.correlationIdHeaderName, correlationId);

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

and will be registered in a simple configuration class:

```
import *.AttachCorrelationIdHeaderFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CorrelationConfiguration {
    private String correlationIdHeaderName;

    public CorrelationConfiguration(@Value("${usagebox-scs.headers.correlation-id}") String correlationIdHeaderName) {
        this.correlationIdHeaderName = correlationIdHeaderName;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean attachCorrelationIdFilter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<AttachCorrelationIdHeaderFilter>();
        final AttachCorrelationIdHeaderFilter attachCorrelationIdFilter = new AttachCorrelationIdHeaderFilter(correlationIdHeaderName);

        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(attachCorrelationIdFilter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(-1);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

The exception looked like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:312) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$400(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:65) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:328) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:323) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:305) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.getHeaderNames(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at *.RequestHandleEventListener.handleEvent(RequestHandleEventListener.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:261) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:180) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1074) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And what has this exception to do with the filter? Apparently you are using an `RequestHandleEventListener` and do something in there with the current request in a way you shouldn't be doing it. So the error isn't in the filter but in your `RequestHandleEventListener`.

Comment: Oh, you are  right. I just looked at my filter, because if I removed the filter it worked without the exception. Thank you!